# Logging request and response of click event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used this code to auto click a button at an interval of e.g. 5 millisecond. Now I need to log every click request and its response from server in a file with the exact time of every click with millisecond precision. Can anyone help me to do this.

```
let timerId =setInterval(() => {
 $("#sendRequest").click();

    console.log('clicked');
}, 5);

let stop = 300000;
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop'); }, stop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) : The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds since the [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You can set `let startTime = new Date().getTime();` before `setInterval` and use `new Date().getTime() - startTime` to get `exact` time of `interval call`.

Try is below.

```js
let startTime = new Date().getTime();
let timerId = setInterval(() => {
 //$("#sendRequest").click();

    console.log('clicked' + (new Date().getTime() - startTime));
}, 1000);

let stop = 10000;
setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop'); }, stop);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was usefull. But my main problem was recording response of every request sent to server by every click. How can I log this data to a file or just collect these requests and their relevant responses?

Comment: I guess you need to get response map with time. And `request` might be send through `click` event. So you need to show that `request` part so others can share thoughts or answers.